# Dropdown doesn't shows selected value in Chrome when click on back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, nopcommerce, history.js

My webpage contains a drop-down and I have implemented history.js but on back button, the value of selected item in drop-down is not displayed. It loads items of drop-down with selected value but only not showing in drop-down as a selected item. Also by clicking on back button ajax call is made and that doesn't refresh drop-down. It means that drop-down is not including in ajaxcall, it is out of ajax-call.

This issue raise only in Chrome. My Chrome version is Version 47.0.2526.73 m. This works well in Mozilla Firefox.

The issue is when I click back button in Chrome, dropdown doesn't display default/selected value. It loads all values,too. Only not showing selected value on dropdown. if I remove "selected" property and again add this property by edit Html then it shows dropdown value also.

Here is I have implemented Histroy.js:

```
  $(function () {

History.Adapter.bind(window, "statechange", function () {
    var State = History.getState();
    var url = ((State.data.loadUrl == "undefined") ? State.data.loadUrl : State.url);
    if (typeof (manualStateChange) !== "undefined" && manualStateChange == true) {
        AjaxCall(url);
    }
    else if (typeof (State.data.loadUrl) == "undefined") {
        AjaxCall(url);
    }
    manualStateChange = true;
    return false;
  });    
});
```

And here is my pushState function:

```
function PushStateUrl(stateUrl) {
 manualStateChange = false;
 History.pushState({ loadUrl: stateUrl, rand: Math.random() }, document.title, stateUrl);
}
```

Comment: You have not mentioned your code.It will be good if you mentioned your code too.

Comment: I have added code. Please give me solution.